# When does an artficer regain spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, spell-slots, rests

I've looked on several resources and I can't get to the bottom of whether an Artificer recharges spell slots on short/long rest?

Lots of articles refer to the class as a "short rest caster" or "warlock-like" but I haven't been able to find anything in the handbooks which make it very clear (to me at least).

Some places seem to say short rest:

> This wondrous creation is capable of regenerating its power over a short rest period (1 hour), which allows artificers to regenerate their spell slots much like a warlock can.
> https://gadriel.fandom.com/wiki/Artificer_(DND_5th_edition)

While others say long rest:

> You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a long rest.

It seems to make a huge difference to the power of an artificer, particularly as they gain spell slots very slowly. Is there anything solid to back up the "regain on a short rest" that gets talked about so much?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first link you provided is a homebrew (non-official) class named artificer.

The official artificer (published in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* and *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*) regains their spell slots after a long rest:

> To cast one of your artificer spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher. *You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a long rest.*
>
> -*E:RftLW* pp. 55-56, *TCoE* pg. 11

Comment: I removed the reference to *Wayfinder’s Guide* since it is technically playtest content, not official content.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that makes a lot of sense! I've also seen that Artificers get Arcane Recovery at L5, which does help them recover slots on a short rest, but I can't find much more detail on that? Is that part of the official class too?

Comment: @David258 No it is not. If you want to play an artificer, I recommend purchasing *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, it contains lots of extra options in addition to the artificer.